# What is a good way to divide all columns element-wise by a column-specific scalar in a polars dataframe?

Tags: python-polars

I have a polars dataframe containing some columns with integer values in them, e.g.

```py
>>> import polars as pl
>>> df = pl.DataFrame({'a':[3,3,3],'b':[6,6,9]})
>>> df
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 3   ┆ 6   │
│ 3   ┆ 6   │
│ 3   ┆ 9   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

Now I would like to transform the data in the dataframe to be relative to the value in the first row, i.e. all values in column `a` would be divided by 3, all values in column `b` divided by 6 to receive

```py
>>> df
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ f32 ┆ f32 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1.0 ┆ 1.0 │
│ 1.0 ┆ 1.0 │
│ 1.0 ┆ 1.5 │
└─────┴─────┘
```

What would be a good way to implement this using polars expressions?

I cannot find a `divide` method on polars Series and it is unclear to me how to get the first value in a column in the polars with_columns context.

Comment: How can `3, 9` be the last row when the dataframe contains `6, 8`? You can use expressions such as: `pl.col("a") / pl.col("a").first()` - there's also `pl.first("a")` as shorthand syntax for `pl.col("a").first()`.

Comment: Poor editing from my side, I had an initial example in the interpreter, then changed the example in the question editor. Thanks, your suggestion seems similar to what I figured out as well.

Comment: Ah, okay. Yeah, you can use `pl.all().first()` if you prefer, but it's the same as `.head(1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution:

```py
>>> import polars as pl
>>> df = pl.DataFrame({'a':[3,3,3],'b':[6,6,9]})
>>> df
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 3   ┆ 6   │
│ 3   ┆ 6   │
│ 3   ┆ 9   │
└─────┴─────┘
>>> df.with_columns(pl.all()/pl.all().head(1))
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ f64 ┆ f64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1.0 ┆ 1.0 │
│ 1.0 ┆ 1.0 │
│ 1.0 ┆ 1.5 │
└─────┴─────┘
```

In case someone has a better suggestion, it would be very much welcome.