# Dividing each column in Polars dataframe by column-specific scalar from another dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, python-polars

Polars noob, given an `m x n` Polars dataframe `df` and a `1 x n` Polars dataframe of scalars, I want to divide each column in `df` by the corresponding scalar in the other frame.

```
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

cols = list('abc')
df = pl.DataFrame(np.linspace(1, 9, 9).reshape(3, 3),
                  schema=cols)
scalars = pl.DataFrame(np.linspace(1, 3, 3)[:, None],
                       schema=cols)
```

```
In [13]: df
Out[13]: 
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ f64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1.0 ┆ 2.0 ┆ 3.0 │
│ 4.0 ┆ 5.0 ┆ 6.0 │
│ 7.0 ┆ 8.0 ┆ 9.0 │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘

In [14]: scalars
Out[14]: 
shape: (1, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ f64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1.0 ┆ 2.0 ┆ 3.0 │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

I can accomplish this easily in Pandas as shown below by delegating to NumPy broadcasting, but was wondering what the best way to do this is without going back and forth between Polars / Pandas representations.

```
In [16]: df.to_pandas() / scalars.to_numpy()
Out[16]: 
     a    b    c
0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  4.0  2.5  2.0
2  7.0  4.0  3.0
```

I found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76307206/what-is-a-good-way-to-divide-all-columns-element-wise-by-a-column-specific-scala) where the scalar constant is already a row in the original frame, but don't see how to leverage a row from *another* frame.

Best I can come up with thus far is combining the frames and doing some... nasty looking things :D

```
In [31]: (pl.concat([df, scalars])
    ...:    .with_columns(pl.all() / pl.all().tail(1))
    ...:    .head(-1))
Out[31]: 
shape: (3, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ f64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1.0 ┆ 1.0 ┆ 1.0 │
│ 4.0 ┆ 2.5 ┆ 2.0 │
│ 7.0 ┆ 4.0 ┆ 3.0 │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Comment: I think you found out a very unique/interesting and clever solution. Consider also just iterating over columns:

df.select(column / scalars[column.name] for column in df.iter_columns())

Comment: @JohnnyCheesecutter OH.. idk why I'm not using generators in `select` like that, that's way way more understandable. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you found out a very unique/interesting and clever solution. Consider also just iterating over columns:

```
df.select(column / scalars[column.name] for column in df.iter_columns())
```

or

```
df.select(pl.col(k) / scalars[k] for k in df.columns)
```

or

```
df.with_columns(pl.col(k).truediv(scalars[k]) for k in df.columns)
```

Answer (score 2):

I was not sure it's not possible, but I tried it and simple arithmetic actually works, if you bring the frames to the same shape. First, use [`Expr.repeat_by()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.repeat_by.html) and then [`Expr.list.explode()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.list.explode.html) lists into rows:

```
python

df / scalars.select(pl.all().repeat_by(len(df)).explode())

┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ f64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1.0 ┆ 1.0 ┆ 1.0 │
│ 4.0 ┆ 2.5 ┆ 2.0 │
│ 7.0 ┆ 4.0 ┆ 3.0 │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Also, apparently you can use arithmetic operations between [`DataFrame()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/index.html) and [`Series()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/series/index.html), but seems like you need to [`transpose()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.transpose.html) your `DataFrame` before doing it, cause it's done per columns (first column of the `DataFrame` is divided by the first value of `Series` and so on):

```py
df.transpose()

┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ column_0 ┆ column_1 ┆ column_2 │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ 1.0      ┆ 4.0      ┆ 7.0      │
│ 2.0      ┆ 5.0      ┆ 8.0      │
│ 3.0      ┆ 6.0      ┆ 9.0      │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘

scalars.transpose().to_series()

[
    1.0
    2.0
    3.0
]


(df.transpose() / scalars.transpose().to_series())
.transpose(column_names=df.columns)

┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ f64 │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1.0 ┆ 1.0 ┆ 1.0 │
│ 4.0 ┆ 2.5 ┆ 2.0 │
│ 7.0 ┆ 4.0 ┆ 3.0 │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

I've quickly tested performance on a bit bigger DataFrames, and all proposed solutions seems to be similar in speed (on my machine):

```py
%timeit 'df.transpose() / scalars.transpose().to_series()).transpose(column_names=df.columns))'
11.4 ns ± 0.892 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000,000 loops each)

%timeit 'df / scalars.select(pl.all().repeat_by(len(df)).explode())'
11.7 ns ± 0.992 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000,000 loops each)

%timeit 'pl.concat([df, scalars]).with_columns(pl.all() / pl.all().tail(1)).head(-1))'
11.5 ns ± 0.369 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000,000 loops each)

%timeit 'df.select(column / scalars[column.name] for column in df.iter_columns())'
11.2 ns ± 0.522 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000,000 loops each)
```